# How do I combine multiple conditions (exists and not exists) checks before inserting a new record in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I would like to build a query to insert a new record, after checking with an EXISTS and a NOT EXISTS condition in two different tables.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `categories` WHERE categories.term_id = 123)
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `terms` WHERE terms.id = 123)
THEN INSERT INTO `categories`(id, term_id, term_type_id)
VALUES ('', '123', '4')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't. inserts can't be "conditional". they have no `where` clause. if you want a conditional insert, then you'd have to write a stored procecedure and wrap the insert in conditional code. or do the "deciding" in client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

You can first check the desired record from the table with a select query. If the query returns the 0 rows then execute the insert statement otherwise no need to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You an use indices to enforce this behavior.

- `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM`terms`WHERE terms.id = 123)`

  To enforce this, define `categories.term_id` as a foreign key to `terms.id`.
  That way you can not insert a `term_id` into the `categories` table if that is non existent in the `terms` table.
- `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM`categories`WHERE categories.term_id = 123)`

  To enforce this, you need to put a `UNIQUE` index on the `categories.term_id` column. This will block duplicate entries.